# There is already a vedacore folder, but it can't be brought in via the import

Tags: python-3.x, face-detection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cotU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBwIu.png)
How can I solve this problem?
This problem occurs when I use colab to run the official code for the paper "TinaFace: Strong but Simple Baseline for Face Detection" and when I try to run the tools/trainval.py file. This happens.
Tried reinstalling the package but it didn't work

Comment: Don't post code as a screenshot, please write your code